# Enforce optional type typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to enforce that a function can only get called with an optional type

where Optional is defined as

```
type Optional<T> = T | undefined
```

I would like to define a function f so that

```
declare type Foo = { foo: string }
declare var x: Optional<Foo>
declare var y: Foo

f(x) // ts typecheck ok
f(y) // ts typecheck ko
```

Comment: But why ? Generally if a function can handle `T | undefined` it should be fine with `T`.

Comment: I would like to type check that a generic function can only get called on an optional value.

Comment: It is not possible. As union is always represented by one value which is in your example T or undefined. Both values are valid values of this type

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#default-values

Comment: It is indeed not possible to prevent `Foo` from being assignable to `Optional<Foo>`, but the question asks for a signature for `f`, and as far as I can tell it is possible to write such a function, as long as `Optional<Foo>` is not assignable to `Foo`. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell this works:

```
declare function f<T>(v:Optional<T> extends T ? T : never) : any;
```

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=66&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwDwBUB8UAvFDlAD5QCuKAJhAGYIoQ0BQrdAxhmgE7ShIUAGJIkRKAG8o9MQC4oAZ2C8mAcygBfDhG59oANz5QAHgriJUmLKKR4de-lCO8oIBbfZceT%20tU6WKDK4eAAUBnIWyOjY%20FAQJsAQtIokUAD8aQrMBhC8AJRQCmgoIADc7PShJoUA9LVQwKmCugAWugDWUEgdrFUgdQ1NjeBtnVAd4kA)